# Command-line flags with multiple default based on root flags

Tags: python, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, argparse

Suppose you have 3 datasets, each with a different set of optimal parameters(e.g batch_size,lr).
I'm looking for a way to somehow:

```
parser.add_argument('dataset',type=str,default='D1',
choices=['D1', 'D2'])
parser.add_argument('batch_size',type=int,
default='128 if dataset=D1 else '64')
```

**Maybe argparse is not the right tool for me**

I found workarounds like setting the default only to D1 and changing it after the parsing if D2 was chosen, but then I don't get the true default value in the -h output. 
I feel like it can't be I'm the first to want defaults that are based on other flags.

Comment: You can add an argument for dataset and have batch_size default to -1. Then if the batch_size > -1, you know the user inputted it and you leave it alone. Otherwise you change it based on the dataset.

Comment: That way the user wouldn't know the default values for the different datasets. It works, but I just can't believe no one interfaced such problem before

Comment: The `-h` help isn't meant to reflect any dynamic values.  It displays `parser.print_help()`, the help that would generated without parsing any of the inputs.

Comment: Correct, and I think it's reasonable to want the user to know the different default values given different settings

Comment: have you looked at the subparsers mechanism?  That's the only builtin mechanism for making one set of arguments depend on another.